# Confused with Cayley's Theorem in group theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Cayley's Theorem: Every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations.

$\mathbb Z_6$ is a group and $S_3$ is a permutation, but $\mathbb Z_6$ is not isomorphic to $S_3$.

$\mathbb Z_6$ is abelian while $S_3$ is not, hence they are not isomorphic.

So, what is going on here? I thought every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/(6)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_6$. Which is a group of permutations. "A group of permutations" means "a subgroup of some symmetric group".

Comment: But isn't a symmetric group a group of permutations as well?

Comment: Yes, a symmetric group is also a group of permutations. $S_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: Why is $\mathbb Z_6$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_6$? Why specifically $S_6$?

Comment: Because an $n$-cycle generates a cyclic group of order $n$, so a cyclic group of order $n$ is clearly isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ by choosing an $n$-cycle the generator is mapped to. Trivially, we can embed it also in all $S_m$ for $m > n$. In the case $\mathbb{Z}_6$, we can also embed that as a subgroup of $S_5$ (but not of $S_k$ for $k \leqslant 4$), but that is less obvious.

Comment: Since the 6 cycle is a subgroup of $S_6$ wouldn't the 6 cycle not be abelian since $S_6$ isn't abelian?

Comment: In every group $G$, for every element $x\in G$, the group generated by $x$ is abelian (cyclic even, by definition). Every non-abelian group has hence nontrivial abelian subgroups.

Comment: How is $\mathbb Z_6$ isomorphic to $S_5$?

Comment: It isn't. But $S_5$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: U said its not obvious so now im curious. What is the generator of that subgroup? Certainly there exists 2 generators since $\mathbb Z_6$ has two generators.

Comment: For example $(1\,2\,3)(4\,5)$ is an element of $S_5$ generating a cyclic group of order $6$. It's not hard to see, just not as obvious as $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)$.

Comment: No, $S_3$ is **not** a permutation. It is a **group** of permutations. And, "every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations" does not mean "every group is isomorphic to **every** group of permutations", it means that "every group is isomorphic to **some** (wisely chosen) group of permutations. For example, $\mathbb Z_6$ is isomorphic to the permutation group $\{(1\ 2\ 3)(4\ 5),(1\ 3\ 2)(4)(5),(1)(2)(3)(4\ 5),(1\ 2\ 3)(4)(5),(1\ 3\ 2)(4\ 5),(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)\}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more precise statement of Cayley's theorem states that if $|G| = n$, then $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

In this case, $|\mathbb{Z}_6| = 6$, so $\mathbb{Z}_6 \leq S_6$.  In particular, it will be the subgroup generated by the $6$-cycle $\sigma = (1,2,3,4,5,6)$.

Comment: Is the 6 cycle abelian? $S_6$ is not abelian, is it?

Comment: @JohannFranklin, I had a slight typo in my original response, so definitely re-read my post.  The subgroup the 6-cycle generates is abelian.  It is true that $S_n$ is not abelian for any $n \geq 3$.  However, it *is* possible to have abelian subgroups of a nonabelian group.

Comment: An even more price statement would replace "is a subgroup" with "is isomorphic to a subgroup".

Comment: @bof, Indeed!  But that's always a mouthful. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It can be a subgroup of a group of permutations, not the whole group! For example,

$$C_6\cong \langle\; (1,2,3,4,5,6)\;\rangle\le S_6\;$$

Comment: What is $C_6$??

Comment: Same as $\mathbb{Z}_6$ @JohannFranklin.  C stands for cyclic.

Comment: A usual notation for the cyclic group of order 6, @JohannFranklin

Comment: Doesn't that 6 cycle have 6! elements? How can $C_6$ be isomorphic to that cycle?

Comment: @JohannFranklin, I'm losing you: with your notation, it is $\;C_6\cong\Bbb Z_6=\;$  the cyclic group with six elements.

Comment: You said C6 = Z6. Doesn't the 6-cycle (123456) have 6! elements?

Comment: No @JohannFrankli ! A cycle is one single element, and the (cyclic!) group generated by it in $\;S_6\;$ has six (6) elements...

Answer (score 3):

The group $S_n$ has order $n!$ (in group theory it's customary calling *order* the number of elements in the group).

If your interpretation were correct, there wouldn't exist groups with order $3$, $4$, $5$ and so on. But for every natural number $m>0$, there is a group of order $m$, for instance the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, $S_n$ is not abelian as soon as $n>2$, so general abelian groups would not be covered.

What Cayley's theorem says is that for every group $G$ there are $n>0$ and a subgroup $H$ of $S_n$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to $H$. With different terminology, there are $n>0$ and an injective homomorphism (or *embedding*) $G\to S_n$.

For instance, $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of $S_6$
$$
\{\mathit{id},(123456),(135)(246),(14)(25)(36),(153)(264),(165432)\}
$$
that is
$$
\{(123456)^0,(123456)^1,(123456)^2,(123456)^3,(123456)^4,(123456)^5\}
$$
It is also isomorphic to the subgroup of $S_5$
$$
\{\mathit{id},(123)(45),(132),(45),(123),(132)(45)\}
$$
that is
$$
\{(123)(45)^0,(123)(45)^1,(123)(45)^2,(123)(45)^3,(123)(45)^4,(123)(45)^5\}.
$$
(here *id* stands for the identity permutation).

Note also that the usual proof of Cayley's theorem will embed $S_3$ in $S_6$, because it proves the existence of an injective homomorphism $G\to S_n$ where $n=|G|$.